# laravel search and get between two field

Tags: php, laravel

i need to get numbers between to field i used whereBetween but i'm not get right results
my input filed
un_price_from and
un_price_to

and my controller

```
        $unit = DB::table('units')->whereIn('un_status', [1]);

        if ($request->has('un_price_from','un_price_to')){
            $unit->whereBetween('un_price', [$request->un_price_from, $request->un_price_to]);
         }
        elseif ($request->has('un_price_from')){
            $unit->where('un_price', $request->un_price_from);
        }
        elseif ($request->has('un_price_to')){
            $unit->where('un_price', $request->un_price_to);
        }
```

Comment: well, what do you get? where do you get it from? any more details will be helpful. This piece of code doesn't look wrong.

Answer (score -1):

i found the problem it was in database the ( Price ) field was **varchar** and i changed to **DECIMAL** and worked fine. 
thanks to all